# Store addEventListener in variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables, addeventlistener

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game and I am trying to store some text in a variable when a click event takes place using addEventListener (when a user clicks a button to select either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors) but when I console.log the variable I get 'undefined'.  I have a return statement in there and if I console.log within the arrow function and click the button I get the right result but outside I am getting undefined.  Here is the code I have

```
let playerRock = document.querySelector('#rock');


let rockChoice = playerRock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let choice = e.target.innerText
    console.log(choice) // returns "Rock"

    return choice   
});

console.log(rockChoice) // returns "undefined"
```

I have another function that grabs the text from the button when I click it and then puts it on the screen so I know e.target.innerText works to some extent.  Here is that code:

```
function getAndDisplayText(e) {
    let choice = e.target.innerText
    displayPlayerChoice.textContent = choice;
    let computerChoice = computerPlay()
    displayComputerChoice.textContent = computerChoice
    versus.textContent = "vs:"
}

playerRock.addEventListener('click', getAndDisplayText)
```

Any help or insight is much appreciated

Comment: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value) does not return any value under any circumstance in spec-compliant interpreters, and it's not clear where you got this idea from (if you can cite a source to the contrary, we can try to help clear up your confusion on this). You'll have to use the callbacks as designed to pass event data to and from the code in which you want to use it (as you seem to have done in the second snippet) Can you elaborate on why the second snippet is insufficient to meet your requirements?

Comment: And even if it did you would still be trying to log a value _before_ the click event happens, and `rockChoice` would be still be `undefined`.